# HTTP Status 404 Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm learning Spring. I created a spring mvc project. If i write these lines in root-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jaive.test.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jaive.test.service" />

<import resource="data.xml" />
```

then i get HTTP Status 404. If not, everything works fine. I want to know about these lines and why this happenning. I use Apache Tomcat 7.

data.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang              http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="configLocation">
    <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
<property name="configurationClass">
    <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: There are many reasons for 404's so post your stacktrace so we can reduce the problem easier

Answer (score 0):

did you config the controller,because 404 is always happend to not found the controller, and I noticed that you just not config your controller.

Comment: This is not always true, sometimes tomcat is configured badly and give this error.